# Can I load a JSON file as one big string in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

You know how can open a json file in a text editor and then just do control-F and search for whatever you want?  Is there a way to do that in Python by converting the contents of a JSON into one big string and then do something like:

if text in string:
Print(“True”)

Just wondering if that’s possible in Python.

Comment: What did you try and didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
jdata = json.loads(open ('filename.json').read())
t = str(json.dumps(jdata, indent=4, sort_keys=True))